# Haskell Repa meaning of BoundFixed?

Tags: haskell, repa

In the Repa package, there is a [`Boundary`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.11/repa-3.4.0.1/Data-Array-Repa-Stencil.html#t:Boundary) datatype:

```
data Boundary a
        = BoundFixed !a
        | BoundConst !a
        | BoundClamp
        deriving (Show)
```

I understand what is meant by `BoundConst` (cells outside of the array are treated as single value), and I understand what is meant by `BoundClamp` (cells outside of the array are the same values as the closest array cell).

What is meant by `BoundFixed`? The description is *Use a fixed value for border regions*. What is the "border region"? Are these all the edge cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the source code for [`mapStencil2`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.11/repa-3.4.0.1/src/Data-Array-Repa-Stencil-Dim2.html#mapStencil2) and [`partitionForStencil`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.11/repa-3.4.0.1/src/Data-Array-Repa-Stencil-Partition.html#partitionForStencil), it looks like the border region is any cell whose value would be computed using cells outside the input array. `BoundConst` uses a constant value outside the array as the input to the convolution when sampling cells outside the array. `BoundFixed` uses a constant value as the result any time the convolution would depend on a value outside the array.

You could easily test this with a 3x3 identity convolution on a small image. `BoundConst` and `BoundClamp` shouldn't change the image at all. `BoundFixed a` would draw one cell `a` border on the image. `BoundFixed` with a 2x2 identity convolution should draw the border on only two sides of the image. I can't recommend using `BoundFixed` for anything other than drawing borders, since the same convolution would produce different results just because of the stencil size.